# Get values in between specific tag using PHP GetBetween

Tags: php, html, dom

I would like to split text in between **< li> and < /li>** tag contents and display into a textarea.

My database values are saved in following format

```
<ul>
  <li>Test1</li>
  <li>Test2</li>
  <li>Test3</li>
  <li>Test3</li>
</ul>
```

I would like to fetch each value in between **< li > and < /li >** and display in a textarea. (maximum only 4 text-areas).

```
<?php
$sql="SELECT * FROM product_name";
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());        
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

function GetBetween($value1="",$value2="",$dbvalue){
$temp1 = strpos($pool,$value1)+strlen($value1);
$result = substr($dbvalue,$temp1,strlen($dbvalue));
$dd=strpos($result,$value2);
if($dd == 0){
$dd = strlen($result);
}

return substr($result,0,$dd);
?>  


<textarea  name="description1">
<?php echo GetBetween("<li>","</li>",$row['description']);?>
</textarea>

<textarea  name="description2"></textarea>
<textarea  name="description3"></textarea>
<textarea  name="description4"></textarea>
```

In my first Textarea database values are fetching. But I do not know how to display 2,3 and 4 each values into the respective Textares.

I am expecting following output:

```
<textarea  name="description1">Test1</textarea>
<textarea  name="description2">Test2</textarea>
<textarea  name="description3">Test3</textarea>
<textarea  name="description4">Test4</textarea>
```

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Thought about using [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) or [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)? Both of which should be able to process XHTML tags.

Comment: Sir, I am beginner in PHP. First time I heard about DOMDocument or SimpleXML. Just reading about it. Thanks

Comment: I just realized you were storing HTML in your database.  You should probably stop doing that.

Comment: I think SimpleXML is a big easier for beginners.  But what would be even easier is if you stored these values in a normalized database (meaning each value in it's own row) or if it is one description, just store them on separate lines in a TEXT field.  Then read each line and write the HTML when you print it on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest an example:

```
<?php
$str = "<ul>
  <li>Test1</li>
  <li>Test2</li>
  <li>Test3</li>
  <li>Test3</li>
</ul>";

preg_match_all('/<li ?.*>(.*)<\/li>/',$str,$matches);

if(!empty($matches[1])){
   foreach($matches[1] as $key=>$text){
      echo '<textarea  name="description'.($key+1).'">'.$text.'</textarea>';
   }
}
}
```

Comment: @ CaHuyuh: in this example it works fine. But it will not work when Database value store in $str. It will act as html.

Comment: If getting data from database, you can store the string in a buffer block like that: $str = <<<EOF content goes here.... EOF; or by using php helper functions like mysql_real_escape_string or html_entity_decode

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example that should get you started:

```
<?php

$html = <<<HTML
<ul>
  <li>Test1</li>
  <li>Test2</li>
  <li>Test3</li>
  <li>Test3</li>
</ul>
HTML;

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$id = 1;
// find all <li> elements
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('li') as $element) {
    // then print <textarea> elements
    printf('<textarea name="description%d">%s</textarea>',
        $id++,
        htmlspecialchars($element->nodeValue)
    );
}
```